# Inserting new column to an already existing excel file using jxl api

Tags: java, jxl

I'm using jxl api for editing an existing excel file. 
But when i try to add a new column and write the sheet its showing null pointer exception.
The code that I'm using is as shown below :

```java
File file = new File("d:\\test.xls");
Workbook workbook;
WritableWorkbook copy = null;
if (file.exists()) {

    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\TEMP\\temp.xls"),
                workbook);
    } catch (BiffException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        fnf.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   
WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);

sheet.insertColumn(2); //this statement causes error  
                      //if I comment it the code works fine

try {
    copy.write();
    copy.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem and insert new column .

I'm able to edit the single cells of excel successfully and write the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the api you are using is not the best one. I also had this problem (nullpointer exception at the insertcolumn line) and couldnt find any solution until I downloaded [jexcelapi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.9%20%28Java%201.6%29/jexcelapi_2_6_9.zip/download).

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The above code can run fine  in my computer. you'd better to tell us the exception information and put the whole code here.

Comment: It works until you add a data filter in the file.Pls Check if it works after adding a data filter in the file.

Answer (score 1):

We can insert a new cell and thus a new row/column like this-

```
Workbook aWorkBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Originalfile.xls"));
        WritableWorkbook aCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("Originalfile.xls"), aWorkBook);
        WritableSheet aCopySheet = aCopy.getSheet(0);//index of the needed sheet
        WritableCell aWritableCell = aCopySheet.getWritableCell(1,1);//no need!
        jxl.write.Label anotherWritableCell =  new jxl.write.Label(1,12 ,"SUN");
                //position of the new cell in column,row
            //can be a new Label() or new Number() or new Formula

            aCopySheet.addCell(anotherWritableCell);

        aCopy.write();
        aCopy.close();
```

I am not clear on what the insertRow() or insertColumn() methods do. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution works fine if you want to write a new cell. But my file already contain values and I want to insert new column. that means all the info that is currently present in file should shift to the next column.

Comment: the code is useful when u wanna write cells to an already existing excel file.Ur problem sounds like u just have to first read the already existing rows-take the data in the last row-insert the new row using the code above and populate the new cell with the last cell's data and then write the last cells data to the last row, so, <b>all u need is to add some more logic to the above code..</b>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with **jxl**, you must use **apache poi** http://poi.apache.org/
(or something else if there is anything else)

With jxl you can only read or write workbooks, not edit existing ones.
You can also copy workbook and edit newly created.
WritableWorkbook newWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(newFile, workbookTemplate, wbSettings);
But you will lose a lot of formating ald all AutoFilters, which was mine problem when I was useing jxl.

Great examples are here
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html
http://www.kodejava.org/browse/49.html